# Newport Picomotor Control using python

Tags: python, .net

I have a Newport picomotor that I am controlling using the Picomotor controller model 8742. I am using Newport's .dll files that they provide with the Picomotor Application to send commands to the controller.

The code is the following:

```
import sys
import os
import inspect,fixedint
# Import the .NET Common Language Runtime (CLR) to allow interaction with .NET
import clr
import numpy as np
from ctypes import c_int32 as int32

print ("Python %s\n\n" % (sys.version,))

strCurrFile = os.path.abspath (inspect.stack()[0][1])
print ("Executing File = %s\n" % strCurrFile)

# Initialize the DLL folder path to where the DLLs are located
strPathDllFolder = os.path.dirname (strCurrFile)
print ("Executing Dir  = %s\n" % strPathDllFolder)

# Add the DLL folder path to the system search path (before adding references)
sys.path.append (strPathDllFolder)

# Add a reference to each .NET assembly required
clr.AddReference ('UsbDllWrap')
clr.AddReference('CmdLib8742')
clr.AddReference('CmdLib')
clr.AddReference('System')
clr.AddReference('DeviceIOLib')
# Import a class from a namespace
from Newport.USBComm import *
from Newport.DeviceIOLib import *
from System import String,Int32
from System.Text import StringBuilder
from System.Collections import Hashtable
from System.Collections import IDictionaryEnumerator
from NewFocus.PicomotorApp import CmdLib8742 as cmd

# import Int32
import System,Newport,NewFocus,Newport.DeviceIOLib

print(inspect.getmembers(Newport))
print(NewFocus.PicomotorApp.CmdLib8742.GetPosition.__doc__)
bStatus = oUSB.OpenDevices (0, True)

if (bStatus) :
    oDeviceTable = oUSB.GetDeviceTable ()
    nDeviceCount = oDeviceTable.Count
    print ("Device Count = %d" % nDeviceCount)

    # If no devices were discovered
    if (nDeviceCount == 0) :
        print ("No discovered devices.\n")
    else :
        oEnumerator = oDeviceTable.GetEnumerator ()
        strDeviceKeyList = np.array ([])

        # Iterate through the Device Table creating a list of Device Keys
        for nIdx in range (0, nDeviceCount) :
            if (oEnumerator.MoveNext ()) :
                strDeviceKeyList = np.append (strDeviceKeyList, oEnumerator.Key)

        print (strDeviceKeyList)
        print ("\n")

        strBldr = StringBuilder (64)

        # Iterate through the list of Device Keys and query each device with *IDN?
        for oDeviceKey in strDeviceKeyList :
            strDeviceKey = str (oDeviceKey)
            print (strDeviceKey)
            strBldr.Remove (0, strBldr.Length)
            nReturn = oUSB.Query (strDeviceKey, "*IDN?", strBldr)
            print ("Return Status = %d" % nReturn)
            print ("*IDN Response = %s\n" % strBldr.ToString ())
else :
    print ("\n***** Error:  Could not open the devices. *****\n\nCheck the log file for details.\n")

key = String(strDeviceKey)
print(type(key))
cmd.RelativeMove(key,Int32(2),Int32(5))


# Shut down all communication
oUSB.CloseDevices ()
print ("Devices Closed.\n")
```

However, whenever I run the code, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\User1\PycharmProjects\Hardware_Control_I1100_PY3\USB Sample.py", line 85, in <module>
> cmd.RelativeMove(key,Int32(2),Int32(5))
> TypeError: No method matches given arguments for CmdLib8742.RelativeMove: (<class 'System.Int32'>, <class 'System.Int32'>)

The .dll files can be found in the software installation folder. The link to the software is: https://www.newport.com/medias/sys_master/software/software/h4b/he7/9139939803166/PicomotorApp-2.1.5.zip. Can someone please help me figure out the datatype issue of Int32 as shown in the error message? Thanks in advance.